# Digits - match contact from non Digits user

Tags: ios, contacts, google-fabric

[Sorry if this is not very adapted to SO, Digits' support links to SO]

In my iOS app, some users login with Digits, and some don't. I still want to be able to connect all of them using their contact book through Digits'contact matching.

For instance, assuming I have:

```
user                     |    A     |    B    |
login method             |  email   |  digits |
contact book permissions |    yes   |   yes   |
digit ID                 |     -    |   bla   |
My app Id                |   foo    |   bar   |
phone number             |    ?     |    123  |
contact book contains    |    123   |    -    |
```

how can I connect users A and B through their contact book ? for user `A` I've tried:

```
let session = DGTSession()
let digitsContacts = DGTContacts(userSession: session)
// logs [Digits INFO]: Attempted to initialize a DGTUsers instance with an invalid user session
// digitsContacts is nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If the another user of your app hasn't logged or used Digits to authenticate as a user, then we can't scan or upload their contacts. Doing so would be problematic on a few different levels.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Mike. As a follow up question, is it possible to access the data of the contacts stored in Digits from `DGTContacts` or `DGTContactsUploadResult` or something else? I  guess you're doing some nice normalization on phone numbers compare to the raw contact data I can get directly. That'd help to try to do matched for non Digits users

Comment: Anytime, and there isn't a way to access the raw data currently.